# Changing color every second using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to change the color of a SVG structure from red to white and white to red using React Hooks. The problem is that after a few seconds the color starts changing rapidly instead of every second. I'm not understanding where I'm going wrong in the code.

Here is the useState.

```
const[rectColor, rectColorSet] = useState('red')
```

And the useEffect for changing the color.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(rectColor === 'red'){
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            rectColorSet('white')
        }, 1000)
    }
    // console.log('timer',timer)
    else if(rectColor ==='white'){
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
            rectColorSet('red')
        }, 1000)
    }
})
```

And this is the place where I use the state which contains color.

```
 d={`
     M-0.20 0 L-0.20 0.30 L0.20 0.30 L0.20 0 L-0.20 0
  Z`}
            
     fill={props.value ? "green" : rectColor}
        />
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few seconds, the color starts changing rapidly instead of every second because you put [] in useEffect.

If you want to run an useEffect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as the second argument in useEffect hook.

And You should use `setTimeout()` intend of `setInterval()`

So you should write your useEffect like this:

```
const [red, setRed] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalID = setTimeout(() => {
    setRed(red => !red);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 4):

Every render's setting a new interval. Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, and don't forget to clean up the effects:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (rectColor === 'red' || rectColor === 'white') {
        const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
            rectColorSet(rectColor === 'red' ? 'white' : 'red');
        }, 1000);
        return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    }
});
```

Or toggle between a boolean instead of using a string for state. If you add other state that might change, using a single interval when the component mounts might be easier to manage:

```
const [red, setRed] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
  const intervalID = setInterval(() => {
    setRed(red => !red);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
}, []);
```

Comment: Question: why does this happen? I actually just encountered the same issue and was kinda perplexed by it and couldn't figure out why this useEffect without the clearInterval gets all funky

Comment: `useEffect(() => { /* stuff */ })` calls `useEffect` without a dependency array, which tells React to run the callback - the `stuff` - every time the component re-renders. So if the component renders 3 times in a second, 3 intervals will be active after that second. The function returned by the callback - if any - will run as cleanup whenever the component unmounts, or when the component re-renders, given the dependency array.

Comment: With no dependency array, the `return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);` means that `clearTimeout(timeoutID);` runs every time the component re-renders, just before the *next* render's `const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {` runs.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to replace `setInterval()` with `setTimeout()`

and rather than declaring everthing seperately use OR in the conditional and clean up the code.

Comment: Thanks the above answer by @CertainPerformance also works.